# 1-particle momentum eigenfunction in terms of field operator for real Klein-Gordon field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction

Suppose $\phi(x)$ is a real Klein-Gordon field, then the single-particle wave function $\psi(x)$ corresponding to a momentum $p$ is given by (QFT, Ryder)
$$\psi_p(x)=\langle0|\phi(x)|p\rangle.$$
The calculated result is just as expected ($e^{-ipx}$). 
But is this by definition or does it come from somewhere else?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127796/what-is-the-analogy-of-x-rangle-in-quantum-field-theory

Comment: Could you make your question a little more precise? I don't quite understand what you're confused about. You can plug in the mode expansion for $\phi(x)$ and derive the result. Do you want to know why we should expect this result?

Comment: @Ed, I guess (idk) that whilst $e^{ipx} = \langle0|\phi(x)|p\rangle$ is straightforward, it's unclear why it should be that $\langle0|\phi(x)|p\rangle = \psi_p(x)$.

Comment: @innisfree Yes, this is exactly what I meant