# What does a quantized field in QFT do?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I'm studying for an exam called Introduction to QFT. One of the main topics in this class is the quantized free fields.

I can now find the fields that solve the Klein-Gordon equation and the Dirac equation, but I don't really know what they do.

For example: if we are considering a Klein-Gordon scalar-free field, we would get something like this:
$$
\phi(X) =\int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^{2/3} \omega_p} (e^{iP_\nu X^\nu} a_p + e^{-iP_\nu X^\nu} a^\dagger_p)
$$
$$
P_0=\omega_p=\sqrt{m^2+p^2} 
$$

Now my problem is: what does this operator exactly do?
I know what $a_p$ and $a^\dagger_p$ do, but I'm not really sure about $\phi(X)$.

We do also define $\phi(X) = \phi^+(X) + \phi^-(X)$, with
$$
\phi^+(X) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^{2/3} \omega_p} e^{iP_\nu X^\nu} a_p
$$
$$
\phi^-(X) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^{2/3} \omega_p} e^{-iP_\nu X^\nu} a^\dagger_p
$$
My understanding is that $\phi^-(X)$ creates a particle in the space-time coordinate $X$, but is this true? If this was correct, $\phi^-(X)|0>$ would be an eigenfunction of the time-position operator.

Furthermore $\phi^{+\dagger}(X)=\phi^-(X)$, which means that $\phi^\dagger(X)=\phi(X)$, and so $\phi(X)$ is a self-adjoint operator. Does this mean that $\phi(X)$ is connected to some observable? What are its eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

My biggest concern here is on the effect of the operator $\phi(X)$: what does it do? does it define an observable?

I feel like these should be some very important questions for someone learning QFT, but I'm having a hard time finding the answers.

Comment: There are many problems with a (self-adjoint) position observable in relativistic QFT. Also, there are many posts here already regarding the meaning of position states in QFT, and things like $\phi(x)|0\rangle$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it just a mnemonic to call $\phi (x)|0\rangle$ a particle at position $x$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/718893/) And also the links therein